# Import data from .db file to powerbi

Tags: powerbi

I have a .db extention file in azure data lake.
I want to fetch data from that .db file to powerbi.

Can you please help me on this?

I am able to import the .db file itself but I want data which is present inside that .db file

Answer (score 0):

A .db file is probably (?) a SQLite database file. To import it's data in Power BI use the ODBC connector. To make this work you also need to install a SQLite ODBC driver on your device, that you can get from here: http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc.